# Opencart Info Page

Tags: opencart

OK, I have been searching for quite some time, and this has me baffled.
I'm trying to add an ad that will pull up more info in the main content section.

If you look at http://teachingforapples.com/ , you'll see 2 links below the orange ad on the left. The only difference between those links is the information ID. However, they behave very differently. The one that says 'about' opens inside the main content area, but the one that says 'referral' opens full window.

There's nothing in the document content that would change this behavior.
The links are made exactly the same in the code except for the ID #.
The generated code shows the same kind of link, neither one has a target attrib.
I can't find anything in any of the modules that has logic code that looks at the doc id #.

So, I started looking at the database. I looked at all the information tables, but don't see anything different between the 2 pages.

Can someone point me in the right direction please? I feel that it must be something simple, but I just can't find it.

Thanks

P.S. the Information module is NOT installed.

Here's the information.php file.

```
<?php 
class ControllerInformationInformation extends Controller {
    public function index() {  
        $this->language->load('information/information');

        $this->load->model('catalog/information');

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('common/home'),
            'separator' => false
        );

        if (isset($this->request->get['information_id'])) {
            $information_id = (int)$this->request->get['information_id'];
        } else {
            $information_id = 0;
        }

        $information_info = $this->model_catalog_information->getInformation($information_id);

        if ($information_info) {
            $this->document->setTitle($information_info['title']); 

            $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                'text'      => $information_info['title'],
                'href'      => $this->url->link('information/information', 'information_id=' .  $information_id),           
                'separator' => $this->language->get('text_separator')
            );      

            $this->data['info_id'] = $information_id;
            $this->data['heading_title'] = $information_info['title'];

            $this->data['button_continue'] = $this->language->get('button_continue');

            $this->data['description'] = html_entity_decode($information_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

            $this->data['continue'] = $this->url->link('common/home');

            if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/information/information.tpl')) {
                $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/information/information.tpl';
            } else {
                $this->template = 'default/template/information/information.tpl';
            }

            $this->children = array(
                'common/column_left',
                'common/column_right',
                'common/content_top',
                'common/content_bottom',
                'common/footer',
                'common/header'
            );

            $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
        } else {
            $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                'text'      => $this->language->get('text_error'),
                'href'      => $this->url->link('information/information', 'information_id=' . $information_id),
                'separator' => $this->language->get('text_separator')
            );

            $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('text_error'));

            $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('text_error');

            $this->data['text_error'] = $this->language->get('text_error');

            $this->data['button_continue'] = $this->language->get('button_continue');

            $this->data['continue'] = $this->url->link('common/home');

            if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/error/not_found.tpl')) {
                $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/error/not_found.tpl';
            } else {
                $this->template = 'default/template/error/not_found.tpl';
            }

            $this->children = array(
                'common/column_left',
                'common/column_right',
                'common/content_top',
                'common/content_bottom',
                'common/footer',
                'common/header'
            );

            $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
        }
    }

    public function info() {
        $this->load->model('catalog/information');

        if (isset($this->request->get['information_id'])) {
            $information_id = (int)$this->request->get['information_id'];
        } else {
            $information_id = 0;
        }      

        $information_info = $this->model_catalog_information->getInformation($information_id);

        if ($information_info) {
            $output  = '<html dir="ltr" lang="en">' . "\n";
            $output .= '<head>' . "\n";
            $output .= '  <title>' . $information_info['title'] . '</title>' . "\n";
            $output .= '  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">' . "\n";
            $output .= '  <meta name="robots" content="noindex">' . "\n";
            $output .= '</head>' . "\n";
            $output .= '<body>' . "\n";
            $output .= '  <h1>' . $information_info['title'] . '</h1>' . "\n";
            $output .= html_entity_decode($information_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "\n";
            $output .= '  </body>' . "\n";
            $output .= '</html>' . "\n";            

            $this->response->setOutput($output);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you use any custom templates extensions that allow you to have different content per each individual item? I have a couple that would cause this if you edited a specific template and this is the only thing I can think of to do this. This isn't standard OpenCart behaviour

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think so. I inherited this. The original PM just sent all the custom work overseas. I've seen some bad modifications already. I'm happy to check anything you suggest though.

Comment: If it's been custom coded then the possible implementations the overseas workers could have used are quite vast. You'll probably need to hire someone to debug it if you're not an OC/PHP developer

Comment: Can you post the file `/catalog/controller/information/information.php` - or if you're using vQmod and the file exists, post `/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_information_information.php`

Comment: OK, added to original post. Just for the record, I am a PHP programmer, but new to OC. Thanks.

Comment: OK - can't really help more than this, but the `info()` method isn't standard in that class and that's what is generating the popup data. Chances are that the url is being rewritten in your `.htaccess`, `index.php` or `/catalog/controller/common/seo_url.php` - The text you need to look for should read `route=information/information/info` though the way they've coded it isn't great and overseas work tends to be thrown in anywhere from past experience, so good luck with the manhunt!

Comment: I think you may have helped. Looking at seo_url.php now. A couple of things have caught my eye. Just need to dig a bit. Will let you know how it turns out. Still, +1 for the good suggestion.

Comment: By manhunt, do you mean me going overseas and strangling these developers? Is that wrong? lol